# Thrift/Erlang string

Tags: erlang, thrift

I'm trying to write a simple Thrift server in Erlang that takes a string and returns a string.

Everything seems to be working up to the point of calling my function:

```
handle_function(Function, Args) when is_atom(Function), is_tuple(Args) ->
case apply(?MODULE, Function, tuple_to_list(Args)) of
    ok -> ok;
    Reply -> {reply, Reply}
end.

test([X]) ->
"You sent: " ++ X.
```

I'm getting a function_clause. The stack trace shows the following:

> {function_clause,   [{server, test,
>   [<<"w00t">>]},
>   {server,handle_function, 2}, ...

My handle_function is copied from the tutorial file so I won't be surprised if I need to tweak it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That last argument of apply should be a list of arguments to 'test', e.g., if tuple_to_list(Args) resulted in:

```
[1]
```

...then:

```
test(1)
```

If `tuple_to_list(Args)` resulted in:

```
[1,2]
```

...then:

```
test(1,2)
```

So, if `{<<"woot">>}` is being passed to `tuple_to_list`, that's going to be:

```
[<<"woot">>]
```

...so:

```
test(<<"woot">>)
```

...but test's signature asks for a list as the argument, so there's a mismatch.

Comment: Aha. I should have looked more closely at the docs for the apply function. I assumed since Args was a list that my function would need to receive one. Also, I needed to indicate a binary parameter a la: test(<<X/binary>>) ->

Comment: How do you mean "indicate a binary parameter"?

Comment: @rvirding In Erlang, a Thrift string is represented as binary data. My function had to receive <<X/binary>> and then decode it with binary_to_list(X).